# Black Hole Coin curve

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, vectors, optimization

I've seen a toy at my local pharmacy called The Black Hole that lets you insert a quarter into a vertical slot. The quarter starts rolling around a curved funnel's circumference and slowly winds its way to the funnel's center.  Unlike most funnel wheels, this funnel's slope is curved from almost horizontal to nearly vertical.  As the quarter rolls around the funnel, it gains speed so that by the time the quarter reaches the funnel's exit, it has rotated from the original vertical orientation to  horizontal.

Watching the coin roll around the funnel is quite mesmerizing as the rolling takes quite a bit longer than you would expect. I suspect that the curve's shape was chosen to maximize the quarter's roll time.

My question is what kind of curve shapes the funnel's cross section?  Is it a parabola, ellipse or catenary? If my suspicion is right that the curve was chosen to maximize roll time, how did the designer go about optimizing the curve's parameters?